# Python redefining entire list of lists of random numbers upon completion of iteration through a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I've worked with Python for a few years now and do not know why it's behaving in the following manner. But that said, I don't think I've ever attempted to work with random numbers in this particular way. Please feel free to check if your python (I use 3.5) is acting the same way.

*Target*: I want to produce a list of lists where each nested list contains the same values but in different order.

**What code I have**:

```
import random

# Define number slots
opts = [1,2,3,4,5]
li = []

for x in range(len(opts)):
    random.shuffle(opts)    # Jumbles the options list
    li.append(opts)     # Append that list to the parent list
```

So, I declare a list of options containing the values that I want. Then I use random.shuffle() to mix-up the list. It is then appended to the master list. But when I go to inspect the results, each nested list has the same ordered list of numbers...

```
>>> for each in li:
    print(each)

[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3]
>>>
```

I originally had code more complex than above, but Because I hadn't worked with pseudo-random numbers in python extensively before, I thought I didn't fully understand the random method. So I kept making the code simpler and simpler. But the outcome was the same. So I finally figured out that the for loop worked as intended until it finished iterating...

#### Code with guided comments:

```
import random

# Define number slots
opts = [1,2,3,4,5]
li = []

print("Now defining the list: \n")
for x in range(len(opts)):
    random.shuffle(opts)    # Jumble the options list
    li.append(opts)     # Append that list
    print("li[{}] = {}".format(x,li[x]))    # Outputs list associated with index

print("\nNow print each index:")
for y in range(len(li)):
    print("li[{}] = {}".format(y,li[y]))
```

Results:

```
Now defining the list:
li[0] = [3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
li[1] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
li[2] = [1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
li[3] = [5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
li[4] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]

Now print each index:
li[0] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
li[1] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
li[2] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
li[3] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
li[4] = [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
```

So, the first output section reflects each appended nested list. The second block of output reflects the same, but after the for-loop completes its iteration.

I'm at a loss why it's behaving this way. For some reason, each nested list is changed to the last appended list but must happen upon or after completion of the for-loop.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You have *exactly one* list named `opts` - you shuffle it multiple times, but that doesn't change the identity of the list.  All of the references to this list that you add to `li` remain references to a single list.  If you view them all at the same time, they will necessarily all have the same content.  Append copies of the list (`li.append(opts[:])` for example) if you want to take snapshots over time.

Comment: If you do `[id(li[i]) for i in range(5)]`, all elements of `li` refer to the same object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are mutable. That means that even though they have one identity, they can have many *states*. What you attempt to do is append the same list a few different times, expecting their current states to stay that way. But in reality, every time you re-shuffle it, *all* instances of that list re-shuffle the same way. Changing one changes them all. What you want is a copy of that list, one that you never change, so it'll appear frozen:

```
for x in range(len(opts)):
    copy = opts.copy() # make a copy
    random.shuffle(copy) # shuffle only the copy
    li.append(copy) # append only the copy
```

Comment: While the solution using copy is correct, the explanation misuses the term instance. What you want to say is that there are multiple references to the same instance, and when it is shuffled, this is reflected in all the references.

Answer (score 1):

You are shuffling the *same* list object repeatedly and appending it to the `li` list every time. Notice how the ID's of the sublists are all the same:

```
>>> import random
>>> opts = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> li = []
>>> for x in range(len(opts)):
...     random.shuffle(opts)
...     li.append(opts)
... 
>>> li
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]]
>>> [id(item) for item in li]
[4392262856, 4392262856, 4392262856, 4392262856, 4392262856]
```

This is the same problem as the [mutable default argument "gotcha"](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

You could solve this problem with a copy:

```
>>> import random
>>> opts = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> li = []
>>> for x in range(len(opts)):
...     new_list = opts.copy()
...     random.shuffle(new_list)
...     li.append(new_list)
... 
>>> li
[[4, 1, 2, 5, 3], [3, 5, 2, 4, 1], [3, 2, 1, 5, 4], [5, 2, 4, 1, 3], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]]
>>> [id(item) for item in li]
[4392411016, 4392262856, 4392410952, 4392399112, 4392399048]
>>> id(opts)
4392411080
```

Beware that if `opts` is large or its elements are large objects, this could end up using a lot of memory. Look into writing your own generator (maybe shuffling a list of indices?) if this is an issue.

In any case, this explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the explainer!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding references to the same list over and over.

You see the result of the last shuffle mirrored in all instances.